# How to use ::csv::split to split and process multiple lines in a CSV file

Tags: csv, split, tcl

I was attempting to use `::csv::split` to extract and process data from multiple lines in a CSV file using TCL. But I could not find a proper documentation about its usage. Can anyone help me with this? Is there a better way to extract data from a CSV file and process it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have pulled in some rows of CSV data into the variable `csv`, you can convert it to a list of tuples and store it in the variable `data` like this:

```
set data {}
foreach row [split [string trim $csv] \n] {
    lappend data [::csv::split $row]
}
```

That's about it. If the CSV data doesn't use commas, you will have to specify the column delimiter in the invocation, like `::csv::split $row \t` or whatever.

Reading directly from a file:

```
set f [open foo.csv]
set data {}
while {[gets row] >= 0} {
    lappend data [::csv::split $row]
}
close $f
```

or, with `fileutil`:

```
package require fileutil

set data {}
::fileutil::foreachLine row foo.csv {
    lappend data [::csv::split $row]
}
```

I've used `csv` a lot and am very happy with it.

There are facilities in `csv` to convert CSV data to e.g. Tcllib `matrix` structures, which can be very handy but not necessary.

Comment: Thanks Peter. But I was wondering if there was anyother way in which I could take each line from an CSV file directly and process the info in that line. Iterating each line in the whole file.

Comment: @KarunJohn: sure, see update. Note that the `csv` `read2*` and `write*` commands can do it in one fell swoop if you use a matrix or a queue.